# Heroku Dash app failing to deploy but successfully builds

Tags: python, heroku, plotly, plotly-dash

Hi I'm building a Dash app using the Python framework and my build logs are suggesting the app was built successfully. In fact when I go to the Heroku website it shows build successful under the build logs. However, when I view the Heroku URL it says application error. Below are the build logs, any help is appreciated. I've also tried restarting the app as Heroku documentation suggests certain errors can only be captures via the restart method but still no errors have appeared in the logs.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the same version as the last build: python-3.9.6
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
-----> Installing python-3.9.6
-----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
         Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
       Collecting Brotli==1.0.9
         Downloading Brotli-1.0.9-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (357 kB)
       Collecting bs4==0.0.1
         Downloading bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
       Collecting click==8.0.1
         Downloading click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
       Collecting colorama==0.4.4
         Downloading colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting dash==1.20.0
         Downloading dash-1.20.0.tar.gz (77 kB)
       Collecting dash-core-components==1.16.0
         Downloading dash_core_components-1.16.0.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
       Collecting dash-html-components==1.1.3
         Downloading dash_html_components-1.1.3.tar.gz (82 kB)
       Collecting dash-renderer==1.9.1
         Downloading dash_renderer-1.9.1.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
       Collecting dash-table==4.11.3
         Downloading dash_table-4.11.3.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
       Collecting Flask==2.0.1
         Downloading Flask-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
       Collecting Flask-Compress==1.10.1
         Downloading Flask_Compress-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 kB)
       Collecting future==0.18.2
         Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
         Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
       Collecting itsdangerous==2.0.1
         Downloading itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
       Collecting Jinja2==3.0.1
         Downloading Jinja2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
       Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1
         Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (30 kB)
       Collecting numpy==1.21.0
         Downloading numpy-1.21.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
       Collecting pandas==1.3.0
         Downloading pandas-1.3.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.6 MB)
       Collecting plotly==5.1.0
         Downloading plotly-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20.6 MB)
       Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1
         Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
       Collecting pytz==2021.1
         Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
       Collecting six==1.16.0
         Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting soupsieve==2.2.1
         Downloading soupsieve-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
       Collecting tenacity==8.0.0
         Downloading tenacity-8.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
       Collecting Werkzeug==2.0.1
         Downloading Werkzeug-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
       Building wheels for collected packages: bs4, dash, dash-core-components, dash-html-components, dash-renderer, dash-table, future
         Building wheel for bs4 (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for bs4 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for bs4: filename=bs4-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=1273 sha256=b96960a58059282bdc82d938f2b1b6fb6b3c09d46f25f346c964360e74cfa048
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-bp3kgu6x/wheels/73/2b/cb/099980278a0c9a3e57ff1a89875ec07bfa0b6fcbebb9a8cad3
         Building wheel for dash (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for dash (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for dash: filename=dash-1.20.0-py3-none-any.whl size=85831 sha256=cfb661b8db05c5bdb3e3d8b83e625e9dfd15352eafca46b4d4a851a496bc5210
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-bp3kgu6x/wheels/4b/cb/a6/817d490fb0a1abb2d078b9e9ee835bf7f039d1fd8b9c61b25e
         Building wheel for dash-core-components (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for dash-core-components (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for dash-core-components: filename=dash_core_components-1.16.0-py3-none-any.whl size=3540991 sha256=0ee679674b63fe67a3be0634132063574ce02e3621d860f273312f2fe8ab3c36
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-bp3kgu6x/wheels/a1/21/97/554773c64b38bf753f189054921c9217174a96d500f15b7f93
         Building wheel for dash-html-components (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for dash-html-components (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for dash-html-components: filename=dash_html_components-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl size=319471 sha256=9d31ced0fc5469eca3d738cf82d1f6e67b8fc4dcfc4670f4f725e0c1ec31886c
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-bp3kgu6x/wheels/f7/eb/55/521dda099c8b09eed0178328cbe10306cb3fee851efd70ae4f
         Building wheel for dash-renderer (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for dash-renderer (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for dash-renderer: filename=dash_renderer-1.9.1-py3-none-any.whl size=1014878 sha256=36518dc881b0aa2d81d6693ce1acfd3fa02fddd94064b0bb6364aca71ae5025e
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-bp3kgu6x/wheels/52/2f/28/956ce9f7763c886d23f0082829bd726e5dacd6c708a5841c77
         Building wheel for dash-table (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for dash-table (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for dash-table: filename=dash_table-4.11.3-py3-none-any.whl size=1827618 sha256=15003b86d61d36cd73121c93b98df95d4b095a1460988acf05dfa8637b88f9de
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-bp3kgu6x/wheels/fb/0c/3d/fd6e565aa34ba87d6d110898b3297d2b78ef70339f1c2a483e
         Building wheel for future (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for future (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for future: filename=future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl size=491059 sha256=c30e1e964c5831e386abe653832f6f508b4e0feafd66f9cbfa8038fa0791d4de
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-bp3kgu6x/wheels/2f/a0/d3/4030d9f80e6b3be787f19fc911b8e7aa462986a40ab1e4bb94
       Successfully built bs4 dash dash-core-components dash-html-components dash-renderer dash-table future
       Installing collected packages: soupsieve, beautifulsoup4, Brotli, bs4, click, colorama, itsdangerous, Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Flask, Flask-Compress, six, tenacity, plotly, dash-renderer, dash-core-components, dash-html-components, dash-table, future, dash, gunicorn, numpy, pytz, python-dateutil, pandas
       Successfully installed Brotli-1.0.9 Flask-2.0.1 Flask-Compress-1.10.1 Jinja2-3.0.1 MarkupSafe-2.0.1 Werkzeug-2.0.1 beautifulsoup4-4.9.3 bs4-0.0.1 click-8.0.1 colorama-0.4.4 dash-1.20.0 dash-core-components-1.16.0 dash-html-components-1.1.3 dash-renderer-1.9.1 dash-table-4.11.3 future-0.18.2 gunicorn-20.1.0 itsdangerous-2.0.1 numpy-1.21.0 pandas-1.3.0 plotly-5.1.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2021.1 six-1.16.0 soupsieve-2.2.1 tenacity-8.0.0
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 113.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v4
       https://senate-dash-app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Here is a 2nd deploy with a specified runtime.txt file. https://gist.github.com/github99er/11bca53aa40938a61b5f9e9dfe92b8f0

Comment: Had u turned on dyno?

Comment: I believe so, I ran ```heroku ps:scale web=1```

Comment: UPDATE: I found out dash bootstrap components was not being imported properly, this has since been added to requirement.txt and now I'm seeing "Internal Server Error" when I deploy and navigate to my Heroku web app.

Comment: UPDATE2: I found out that if I build a multi page source app I need to direct the procfile to index.py not app.py, however, now I see another module error with requests.. It's in my requirements.txt file but not being read for some reason.